# Shared pointers delete recursive data structures recursively and the stack overflows

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++11, recursion, shared-ptr

I have a number of long linked lists (they have up to 20,000 items). They have different beginnings but they can eventually point to the same node from some node onwards. I've decided to let such linked list to grow together and share the memory between them.

That is why I ve decided to implement linked list with shared pointers:

```
#include <memory>
struct SharedLinkedList {
    int someData;
    std::shared_ptr<SharedLinkedList> next;
};
```

This way everything works fine. The linked lists which are no longer needed are deleted. If they share some part with other linked list only their un-shared part is deleted.

The problem apears when longer linked lists without shared parts are about to be deleted. Deleting starts with the first element. This decreases the number of references to the next element which can be also deleted and this repeats recursively until the stack overflows.

Here is the example of code which creates long linked list and then fails deleting it.

```
SharedLinkedList* beginningOfList;
SharedLinkedList* actualElement = new SharedLinkedList();
SharedLinkedList* nextElement;

beginningOfList = actualElement;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { // 100 is OK, 1000 is KO
    nextElement = new SharedLinkedList();
    actualElement->next = std::shared_ptr<SharedLinkedList>(nextElement);
    actualElement = nextElement;
}
delete beginningOfList;
```

I thank in advance for either of the following:

1. Explanation of shared_pointers and of what am I missing. How can I use them? And can it even be done using them? Isn't such sharing of memory the thing for which were the share pointers invented?
2. advice how to reimplement my code
3. This code will be used for scientific computations which will be run on my computer. Can I tweak somehow something in order to have bigger size of stack?

Note that this question is not c++11 specific. I don't care which implementation of shared pointes is used. I even implemented my own shared pointers. This allowed me to have a little longer linked lists but the recursion in destructors and stack overflowing also appeared. And I don't see any way how could be shared pointers implemented without recursion in destructors.

EDIT:

Just to aviod confusions: I want to repeat that the whole lists can be shared. So one could call them trees.

Here is the example:

list1 contains: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

list2 contains: 6,6,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

list3 contains: 10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

I want to represent this in 3 SharedLinkedList which do not waste momory by storing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 several times but they point to the same place. That is why reference counting is needed.

`delete list3;` is supposed to delete only the part which is not shared i.e. elements 10,11,12.

Comment: As far as I understand, the problem is the implementation of the destructor of your `SharedLinkedList`. It apparently calls the destructor of the first item, which then calls the destructor of the next item, and so on recursively. You should easily be able to change the implementation of the `SharedLinkedList` destructor so it does not use recursive function calls (e.g. using a `while`-loop over the elements of the list).

Comment: Why not use a standard `std::list` (or `std::vector`) of `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @jogojapan It looks like `SharedLinkList` uses the compiler-generated destructor.  And you can't really add one that iterates over all of the remaining list;  the whole point is for the nodes to be ref-counted.

Comment: @jamesdlin Well, you need to separate the implementation of the list from that of the list items. Then you can avoid the recursion. (And my understanding is that the ref counts are necessary because the same item may be held by several lists, not because they facilitate the list implementation itself. If it was just that, unique-ptr would be sufficient anyway.)

Comment: @jogojapan I am not sure if you understand what I share. Please see the edits I made.

Comment: @JohnBumper You are right; I don't understand the latest edit. First you say that you share entire lists, but then you say that elements 1, 2, 3 and a few others are shared, but some other elements are not. So you _do_ share individual elements.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I should have said: "Not only individual data elements are shared but whole series of them are."

Comment: The impornant point is that two series can have different beginnings and can share a part from some place in the middle to their common end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `shared_ptr` it  will manage ownership for you. When reference count goes to 0 it will call the destructor of the pointee. Now the pointed to object gets destructed and as an element of it the next shared pointer which destructs the next ... . This results in a recursive way of deallocating memory. Now you could try to deallocate the memory iterative. You only have to keep a reference to next element to avoid its destruction and delete it manually later:

```
void destroy(SharedLinkedList* l) {
  auto next=l->next;  // take 2nd element 
  delete l;           // delete first

  while (next)
    next=next->next;  // move next forward, deleting old next 
  }
```

Comment: `delete l;` would decrese reference numbers in underlaying shared pointer and that would start recursion too.

Comment: @JohnBumper no, first a copy of next is created. So the reference count of the second element is (at least) 2. When `l` is deleted it is 1. The idea is to make a copy of `shared_ptr` to the second element, before loosing the first element. So the second element is not deleted when first element is deleted.

Comment: You are right. I cound't believe that so short code realy work. But it realy does work. It is like a miracle. Especially that `next=next->next;` can delete something looked strange at first sight, but it can. I only needed to take extra care about not iterating through shared part because of time saving. Moving your code to destructor was tricky too because the line `next=next->next` also calls destructor. But I managed to do it and it works fast, flawlessly and doesnt blow the stack. Congratulation to your geniallity and many thanks.

Comment: You can add if(next.use_count() > 1) break; after the next=next->next. That'll speed stuff up a lot, speeding it up from a potentially exponential deletion time to linear on the number of nodes.

Comment: @ithenoob Can you explain how you arrive at a potentially exponential deletion time? Adding `if (next.use_count () > 1) break;` will lead to a potential race condition. Even if the test passes, the other owners may have released the object before `destroy` destructs `next`.

Comment: @Marc I arrived at it by having 5 fewer years of experience than I do now :P . I had somehow thought that `destroy` was either the destructor, or a fn which was to be called on each instance of `SharedLinkedList` instead of each "head". In fact _that_ would only add up to at most quadratic time complexity in worst case. I believe the `shared_ptr` "shared state" is thread safe (the logic+state maintaining reference count), so there would be a race condition only in that the bad recursive delete behavior would be initiated. Threads weren't considered at that time. My comment should be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

In general, `shared_ptr` is probably *not* a good idea for
linked lists, for the reason you point out.  In this case, you
probably have to do it by hand, maintaining a parent count in
each node.  (It's probably possible to work out some sort of
loop which avoids the stack overflow with `shared_ptr`, but the
results would probably be more complex than managing the memory
by hand.)