# Insert linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying do a simple insert Node to last position of linked list. But I am running into trouble.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

Node* Insert(Node* head, int data);
Node* print(Node* head);
void ReverseIterative();


Node* Insert(Node* head, int data)
{
    Node* newNode;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return newNode;
    }

    Node* curr=head;
    while(curr->next!=NULL)
    {
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = newNode;
    return head;
}

Node* printList(Node* head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        cout<<head->data;
        head=head->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    head = Insert(head, 2);
    head = Insert(head, 4);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what im doing wrong. Please help~!  I looked over my logic and everything should be correct. It might be the way I am creating a new node in the insert(). I think there is something wrong with my syntax, but i am not sure what it is. I really hate when this happens...

Thanks for your help

Comment: "running into trouble" is not a very good description of your problem, is it?  Please be **specific**.

Comment: Why would you think it's your syntax? Are you getting a compiler error? If so, then what is it?

Comment: Perfect time to stop looking at the code and step through it with a debugger. Pointer gonna point. One of yours doesn't.

Comment: The code is compilable, but when executing windows says "a.exe has stopped working"

Comment: You never allocate `newNode` on this line: `Node* newNode;`

Comment: Check the output warnings. Should be an uninitialized variable in there.

Comment: I looked at another tutorial, it just has Node *newNode

Comment: @Telenoobies _"The code is compilable,"_ That's the very wrong response for a request to run the code in the debugger. Seen so often, and always the wrong track.

Comment: I can't remember when there was a linked-list question that I did not down and close vote for no aparrent debugging done:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yes these seem to be very prone to that specific issue actually. Managing pointers correctly is error prone doing runtime failures, and need debugging most of the time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there is a small, but persistent, set of developers who consider that the use of a debugger is not necessary.  I've had several arguments with them over the years, and never did find out which insane asylum they escaped from:(

Comment: @MartinJames _"set of developers who consider that the use of a debugger is not necessary"_ I'm mostly putting `cerr`/`logger` outputs first before starting the debugger actually. Especially to do rough narrowing of error sources (e.g. with many iterations before reaching the point of interest). The rest is to inspect the source code thoroughly again and use your brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Insert` function, you never allocate `newNode`.

```
Node* newNode;
```

You need to allocate it like so:

```
Node* newNode = new Node();
```

The program runs correctly after fixing this, and the output is:

```
24
```

http://ideone.com/16XL5W

**EDIT:**
Regarding your comment below, the following lines **do not allocate anything**:

```
Node* newNode;
struct Node* newNode;
```

They are simply declaring variables, because you have identified them as pointers (`*`). Pointers simply point to an object on the heap. In order to actually create an object on the heap, you need to use `new Node()`.

The reason your program crashed is because you were trying to access memory from a pointer that hadn't been initialized.

You can use `malloc` if you want, but you're programming in C++, so as a general rule, never use `malloc` unless you actually need to.

If you are using a compliant compiler, use [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)s, then you never have to worry about `delete`ing things that you `new`.

Comment: Note that using shared pointers for linked lists [may have serious deficiencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804235/shared-pointers-delete-recursive-data-structures-recursively-and-the-stack-overf?s=1|0.7271) limiting these in allocation depth.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A good point. In this case it wouldn't make much sense, but in more high-level applications, `shared_ptr`s are preferred in most cases.

Comment: I am reading C programming language right now. One of the example is

Struct point makepoint(int x, int y)
{
   struct point temp;
   ...
   return temp;
}

It does not do struct point temp = new point()

Comment: In that case, it's calling a function that's returning a `point` object (not a pointer). You should really read up on the difference between heap and stack allocation.

Comment: Look at this guy's example.
https://youtu.be/sYcOK51hl-A?t=12m4s

In his reversal function, he just has struct Node *curr, *pre, *next. 

I am confused...

Comment: Why is it that sometimes he can use Node* node, while other he uses struct Node* node?

Comment: Functionally there's no difference in 99% of all cases. Generally, to reduce the amount of code, don't put `struct` in-front of the type unless you have to. This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729646/using-struct-keyword-in-variable-declaration-in-c) and the accepted answer has a good explanation as to why this is sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the `Node* newNode` allocation (uninitialized variable error), the following will throw a return value error:

```
Node* printList(Node* head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        cout << head->data;
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

You have set `Node*` as the return type but this function has no `return` value. Because this function is printing out your list, it does not need to return anything. Change the return type to `void`.